# How to serialize japanese chars in UTF-8 using GSON?

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, serialization, gson

I am currently using a code (best answer on a question) I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221413/how-to-encode-a-mapstring-string-as-base64-string) everything works properly until you give it a japanese `String` input.

I thought the `UTF-8` charset would do the trick but I am not really sure what part of the code does not allow japanese characters to be serialized.

For example if I serialize something basic like `"ひらがな"` it will output garbage characters.

What I am doing is something like

```
String serialized = serialize("ひらがな");
String deserialized = deserialize(serialized, new TypeToken<String>() {}.getType());
System.out.println(deserialized);
```

But I am getting a garbage `deserialized`.

Can someone please shed some light? Thank you.

Comment: I swear I already saw this exact question today...

Comment: Also please either add a link to the answer you use, or post the complete code for the Serializer instance. Wihtout that code, this question can not be answered...

Comment: @ppeterka66, I have added the link to the original question where I got the code from. Credits to BalusC for the code.

Comment: @ReyLibutan, can you tell me how can I serialize my object to json with UTF-8 Encoding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the exact answer to your question, but I can say I had a similar problem and here was my solution. Maybe it's a hint for you:

I am only using GSON for deserialization. I had to change the following code from

```
json = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(is), parseType);
```

to

```
json = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"), parseType);
```

So the issue was in my input stream reader, not GSON per se. I wonder if you need to use a [string reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) for deserialization or something. Sorry I can't give you a more specific answer.

Comment: This is the same solution I got. Glad you posted since I forgot to post my solution after I solved the problem :D

Comment: how to serialize an object with UTF-8 encoding, help