# ImageView in android

Tags: java, android, firebase

```
Map<String,Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
String name1 = String.valueOf(value.get("base64"));
```

name1 string which contains multiple base64 string how to get and display that in imageview.

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(name1.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT); 
image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0,imageAsBytes.length));
```

the above code to display the base64 in imageview. But name1 string contains multiple base64 values how to display those values in image view android

**EDITED:**

```
System.out.println("Path   " + name1);
System.out.println("1  ");
```

OUTPUT:

```
PATH   base64stringedsfdxf 
       1
PATH   base64stringsdimfd
       1
PATH   base64stringsdvsdic
       1
```

i have printed name1 in console it prints 1st field and 1 then printing other like that.

Now how to display these base64 string in imageview. i don't know how to extract a single value. If i put name1 like above code because of it containing more than 1 base64string unable to display. how to move to next imageview when before printing next base64string.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2221668/4494555

Comment: So `name1` has more than one image in it?

Comment: how do you separate between these multiple base64 string?

Comment: how d you get the multiple images in string , can you post sample string containing multiple images? How do differentiate between each images in the string?

Comment: i assume that you have string name1 with value, "image2@@separator@@image2@@separatoe@@image3,. then you create a string array String names [] = name1.split("@@separator@@", then use it ti display images by using listview or an other methods

Comment: Without seeing sample data or as @deepakjohn141 suggests a snippet of code of how you ended up in the situation, it'll be difficult to help efficiently.

Comment: Your last comment sounds like a good answer @deepakjohn141

Comment: I have edited my post mentioned my issue can you see that and try to give me solution.